# In R, how do I calculate difference between dates when condition is met?

Tags: r, dataframe, date

I have two data frames (`df1` and `df2`) with start and end dates for certain events. I've determined which dates have overlapping events, defined here as having a start date in `df1` that is within the start and end date of `df2`. If overlap occurs then they are labeled as `TRUE`, if there is no overlap then they are labeled as `FALSE`. What I would like to know is...when `Overlap` is `TRUE`, how do I calculate the difference between start times in `df2` and `df1`?

```
> df1$aa
    date_start  date_end    Site
1   2002-04-14  2002-04-21  aa
2   2002-06-26  2002-07-05  aa
3   2002-08-15  2002-08-20  aa
4   2004-05-12  2004-05-19  aa
```

```
> df2$bb
    date_start  date_end    Site
1   2002-04-13  2002-04-19  bb
2   2002-08-11  2002-08-19  bb
3   2005-06-09  2005-06-14  bb
4   2005-08-10  2005-08-14  bb
```

This code determines if there is overlap

```
df1$aa$Overlap <- df1$aa$date_start %in% unlist(Map(':', df2$bb$date_start, df2$bb$date_end))
```

```
> df1$aa
    date_start  date_end    Site    Overlap
1   2002-04-14  2002-04-21  aa      TRUE
2   2002-06-26  2002-07-05  aa      FALSE
3   2002-08-15  2002-08-20  aa      TRUE
4   2004-05-12  2004-05-19  aa      FALSE
```

You can see that there are two events (rows 1 and 3) where `Overlap` is `TRUE`. What I would like to do is determine the time difference (`Diff`) between `date_start` for `df1` and `df2` when `Overlap` equals `TRUE`.

The result I am looking for should look something like this.

```
    date_start  date_end    Site    Overlap   Diff
1   2002-04-13  2002-04-21  aa      TRUE      1
2   2002-08-13  2002-08-20  aa      TRUE      4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve your problem with some nested `for` loops.

```r
# Setup df1
df1 <- read.table(textConnection(
  '    date_start  date_end    Site
1   2002-04-14  2002-04-21  aa
2   2002-06-26  2002-07-05  aa
3   2002-08-15  2002-08-20  aa
4   2004-05-12  2004-05-19  aa'
))
df1$date_start <- as.Date(df1$date_start)
df1$date_end <- as.Date(df1$date_end)

# Setup df1
df2 <- read.table(textConnection(
  '    date_start  date_end    Site
1   2002-04-13  2002-04-19  bb
2   2002-08-11  2002-08-19  bb
3   2005-06-09  2005-06-14  bb
4   2005-08-10  2005-08-14  bb'
))
df2$date_start <- as.Date(df2$date_start)
df2$date_end <- as.Date(df2$date_end)


# Find overlap of dates
df1$Overlap <- df1$date_start %in% unlist(Map(':', df2$date_start, df2$date_end))


# Loop through rows
for (i in 1:nrow(df1)) {

  # Go through only those that overlap
  if (df1[i, "Overlap"]) {

    # Loop through all rows in other data frame
    for (j in 1:nrow(df2)) {

      # Check if within range of df1
      sec_date_range <- df2[j, "date_start"]:df2[j, "date_end"]
      if (df1[i, "date_start"] %in% sec_date_range) {

        # Find absolute difference in start dates
        df1[i, "diff"] <- df1[i, "date_start"] - df2[j, "date_start"]
        df1[i, "diff"] <- abs(df1[i, "diff"])
      }
    }
  }
}

# Filter and print result
df1[df1$Overlap, ]
#>   date_start   date_end Site Overlap    diff
#> 1 2002-04-14 2002-04-21   aa    TRUE  1 days
#> 3 2002-08-15 2002-08-20   aa    TRUE  4 days
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>